# Can I store my ionic app's states in a separate file?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

My ionic app's app.js file which holds all my states, factories and directives has gotten fairly large. So far it has 31 states taking up 189 lines, which is quite an eyesore.
I began to wonder, is there a way I can store my states in a separate file and then include that file in my app.js file?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic','ngCordova','ionic.service.core','ionic.service.push','ngSanitize']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider.
  state('foo', {
    url         : '/foo',
    cache       : false,
    templateUrl : 'templates/foo.html',
    controller  : 'foo'
  }).
  // 29 other states
  state('bar', {
    url         : '/bar',
    cache       : false,
    templateUrl : 'templates/bar.html',
    controller  : 'bar'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/foo');
}
// other stuff
```

Comment: Yes. Extend you app and add more config blocks where you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file `app.route.js` with:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider.
  state('foo', {
    url         : '/foo',
    cache       : false,
    templateUrl : 'templates/foo.html',
    controller  : 'foo'
  }).
  // 29 other states
  state('bar', {
    url         : '/bar',
    cache       : false,
    templateUrl : 'templates/bar.html',
    controller  : 'bar'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/foo');
}
```

And include him in your `index.html` in the next line of `app.js`

Comment: Wow, that was easier than I thought it would be. I named my file app.states.js instead of app.route.js for personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Angular module just for this. Angular Seed is a great example of seperating things out into their own modules: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

At a high level, you'd create a new .js file (state.js) and in it:

**state.js**

```
angular.module('myApp.states', []).config(
  //add your $stateProvider code here.
);
```

And then just reference state.js in your index file and add the new module to your module list

**Index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- do stuff here -->
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="state.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'myApp.state'
])
```